# How to apply two different CSS style to the same div on the same page?

Tags: html, css

My question is that how can I apply two different CSS style to the same div on the same page? I have a page which loads (an iframe which loads) two different images in it and both the images have a div element with the same id, I want to div to have different style from when the div loads once and different when it loads another time.

So how can achieve such a feat?

This is the div's HTML:

```
<div id="sa_moreinfo">
    <a href="" target="_blank">More Information</a>
</div>
```

This is the div's CSS:

```
#sa_moreinfo {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 840px;
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 135px;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: use the parent element and make it separate styles.

Comment: An id should (must) be unique for the whole page. if you want some elements to be of the same style use `class` instead of assigning the same `id`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai How to use parent element? And please explain in details...

Comment: Include a http://jsfiddle.net/ we can better help you

Comment: Sorry can't the code is complex and my company rules prohibit me from doing so...

Comment: I have still not understood how any of the suggestions will work for me, because the <div> already has an id that sets some CSS for the anchor element to appear when it loads once, how can I use the :nth-child element to solve the problem or any other suggested solutions?

I am lost...

Answer (score 1):

According to my comment above, Here is the detailed information.

Look at the following HTML.

```
 <div class="test1">
    <div id="sa_moreinfo">
     <a href="" target="_blank">More Information</a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="test2">
    <div id="sa_moreinfo">
     <a href="" target="_blank">More Information</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now using parent element you can apply `#sa_moreinfo` different styles like below.

```
 .test1 #sa_moreinfo {
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 840px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   width: 135px;
}
.test2 #sa_moreinfo {
   margin: 0px 500px 0px0px;
   float: right;
   position: absolute;
   width: 300px;
}
```

So that based on the parent element `test1` and `test2` it will apply different styles for the same id. But duplicating the ID is not a good practice.

Comment: I don't get it how come it will solve my problem? I don't have two divs nor can I put them there. I have one div which loads in an iframe twice with different background images on each run. That is it loads two times with two different images. And the sa_moreinfo is the div with the element I want in two different places at each loading. So I can have only one div not two...and this loading of the same div with two different image happens in the same iframe/page.

Comment: can you post the exact code after it was loading. so that i can try to  find a way.

Comment: I wish I could...it is company's property plus it is on their server which needs access and I can't really provide you the access credentials...

Answer (score 0):

OK, firstly do not use same IDs multiple times on one page and secondly try to style everything using classes. I would recommend you to add some extra class that would extend the other class on the second div, if you cannot do that use [:nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) selector. Btw avoiding iframes is not bad idea either.

Comment: Can you explicate please?